# why not had already been well rehearsed in this text

Tags: past-tense

Why not "*had already been well rehearsed*" in this text:

> South London called Broadway Sound. Early on the morning of August 12th 1982 the band, comprising of Colin Swan, Geno Buckmaster, Brian Grover and their trusty roadie ‘Robbo’ assembled at the tiny studio to begin recording as many of their songs as they could get down on tape for the tiny budget they had scraped together. As most of the songs **were already well rehearsed** thanks to the band’s busy live schedule, the recording of the first nine songs on this disc were finished by mid afternoon without any problems.

I thought I had understood the reason but I had not  because I was told that" had already been well rehearsed" was not correct but in fact it is so why in this text it is written  were already rehearsed

Comment: The reason is that the reader can easily understand that "were already" points to a prior event in the past just as effectively as putting that section in past perfect.